# Cocoa - Update Property in an other class

Tags: cocoa-touch, class, properties

I am new to iPhone programming and in Cocoa I can't seem to update a property that I synthesized in an other class.

I have two classes which should work together. In the AnimalSelect class the users taps a button. When the button is tapped the user will go to the GamePlay class and the name of the animal he selected should be displayed.

I am working with cocos2d for setting up the game. I know I am doing some basic thing wrong but I haven't figured out what it is.

Here is my simpliefied code so far:

**AnimalSelect.h**

```
@class GamePlay;

@interface AnimalSelect : CCLayer {
    GamePlay *gamePlay;
}
```

**AnimalSelect.m**

```
#import "GamePlay.h"
....

NSString *dierenNaam = @"Test";
gamePlay = [[GamePlay alloc] init];
gamePlay.dierenNaam = dierenNaam;
```

**GamePlay.h**

```
@interface GamePlay : CCLayer {
    NSString *dierenNaam;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *dierenNaam;
```

**GamePlay.m**

```
@synthesize dierenNaam;
....
NSLog(@"Dierennaam is: %@", dierenNaam);
```

I know I am making a beginnersmistake, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I hope someone can help me.

@edc1591 - The problem is that I need this data in the GamePlay class? The user selects the button in the view of the AnimalSelect class and then is transfered to the GamePlay view. In this view I want to display the name of the selected animal. That's why I need the property "dierenNaam" to be updated in the GamePlay Class.

***EDIT***
Updated code:

titelLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:dierenNaam fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:46];
titelLabel.position = ccp (160, 430);
[self addChild:titelLabel];

So I adjusted the code like this:

GamePlay.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLabelTTF *titelLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dierenNaam;

- (void) updateLabel;
```

GamePlay.m

```
@synthesize titelLabel;
@synthesize dierenNaam;


- (void) updateLabel {
    [titelLabel setString:[NSString stringWithString:dierenNaam]];
}
```

AnimalSelect.m

```
gamePlay = [[GamePlay alloc] init];
gamePlay.dierenNaam = dierenNaam;
[gamePlay updateLabel];
[gamePlay release];
```

=== back to basics ===

Here is the new code I tried, because I wanted to go back to basics and get the label updated with just xCode. I created the UILabel outlets and connected everything in the nib-file. Here is the code I used. All NSLog methods are executed, but the label is not updated with the text of the theUpdatedLabel variabel.

**AnimalTestViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Animal;
@interface AnimalTestViewController : UIViewController {

    UILabel *titelLabel;
    UIButton *firstButton;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titelLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *firstButton;

- (IBAction) firstButtonPressed;

@end
```

**AnimalTestViewController.m**

```
#import "AnimalTestViewController.h"
#import "Animal.h"

@implementation AnimalTestViewController
@synthesize titelLabel;
@synthesize firstButton;
@synthesize animal;

- (void) firstButtonPressed {
    NSLog(@"The first button was pressed");
    NSString *newAnimal = @"Horse";
    NSLog(@"The variable newAnimal has a value of: %@", newAnimal);

    NSString *labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Initial text: %@", newAnimal];
    titelLabel.text = labelText;
    [labelText release];

    Animal *theAnimal = [[[Animal alloc] init];
    theAnimal.animalName = newAnimal;
    [theAnimal release];
}
```

**Animal.h**
    #import 
    @class AnimalTestViewController;
    @interface Animal : NSObject {
        NSString *animalName;
    }

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *animalName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

- (void) updateLabel;

@end
```

**Animal.m**

```
#import "Animal.h"
#import "AnimalTestViewController.h"

@implementation Animal

@synthesize animalName;
@synthesize aViewController;

- (void) updateLabel {

    NSLog (@"The variable animalName has a value %@", animalName);
    NSString *theUpdatedLabel = @"The label is updated";
    AnimalTestViewController *aViewController = [[AnimalTestViewController alloc] init];
    aviewController.titelLabel.text = theUpdatedLabel;
}
```

Comment: I see you're trying to edit your post. If you had logged in using the same account you used to post the question in the first place, you wouldn't have needed approval. Please use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to ask a site administrator to merge your accounts into one.

Answer (score 0):

The NSLog has to be inside a function that is called from the AnimalSelect class. It won't log anything otherwise.

Try this:

**AnimalSelect.h**

```
@class GamePlay;

@interface AnimalSelect : CCLayer {
    GamePlay *gamePlay;
}
```

**AnimalSelect.m**

```
#import "GamePlay.h"
....

NSString *dierenNaam = @"Test";
gamePlay = [[GamePlay alloc] init];
gamePlay.dierenNaam = dierenNaam;
[gamePlay logDierenNaam];
```

**GamePlay.h**

```
@interface GamePlay : CCLayer {
    NSString *dierenNaam;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dierenNaam;
-(void)logDierenNaam;
```

**GamePlay.m**

```
@synthesize dierenNaam;

-(void)logDierenNaam {
     NSLog(@"Dierennaam is: %@", dierenNaam);
}
```

If you don't want to have that logDierenNaam function, you could write your own setter and getter function for dierenNaam (and remove the property, and synthesize) and have the setter log the value, but I'm not too familiar with doing that. I'm sure you could find a guide on google.

Comment: But I want to update the dierenNaam string in the GamePlay class and show it's contents in NSLog. Can I do that?

Comment: That indeed was what I meant. Thanx for helping me out. I think I can handle the rest of the code from what you taught me.

Comment: Oh one more question. In the init function of GamePlay.m I created a CCLabelTTF to display the name of the animal that the user clicked. Is it possible to  update the name of the label as soon as the user clicks the button, so that when the user goes to the GamePlay class the correct name is shown?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with cocos2d, but couldn't you just declare the CCLabelTTF in GamePlay.h and then set the text of the label in a function similar to logDierenNaam (which you would have to call when the button is tapped)? Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated the code in my post (last bit of code). But this still returns a null-value. Or should I change the init-function as well?

Comment: I think you can just do [titelLabel setString:dierenNaam]; instead of [titelLabel setString:[NSString stringWithString:dierenNaam]];

Comment: I guess you are right. But in what order do I have to create the label and update it's text? Cause in the init-function of the GamePlay class the menu and the label is created. But the value of the string dierenNaam and the label is updated when the button is clicked in the AnimalSelect class. And after the labeltext is updated the new view is created and pushed in front of the existing view. What is the best place to create the menu and the titelLabel?

Comment: Leaving them in the init function is fine. Then just call the updateLabel method whenever you need to update the label. If you're alloc init'ing the view well before it's pushed to the main window, you might want to wait to create the menu and button to save memory, but if the view is being pushed right away you can leave everything in the init function.

Comment: I still have problems with updating the label. I added a my new code with which I am trying to update a label in the AnimalTestViewController class from the Animal class. But this does not work :(

Comment: You're creating a new instance of AnimalTestViewController when you call updateLabel. Try declaring the function as `- (void)updateLabel:(id)sender` and then instead of `AnimalTestViewController *aViewController = [[AnimalTestViewController alloc] init];`, do `AnimalTestViewController *aViewController = sender;`.

Comment: And how can I call this method? Say I wanted to call it from the firstButtonPressed method?